# IntelliJ executes gradle 'testClasses' every time I run a test

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I want to run tests using IntelliJ IDEA and not gradle. I changed the **Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Run tests using** setting to **IntelliJ IDEA**, but whenever I run a test, IntelliJ still runs the 'testClasses' gradle task.

I have a a different gradle project that runs tests using IntelliJ and it does not execute the 'testClasses' task. It runs tests using IntelliJ as expected. Since it works in one project but not the other, I assume there is a project level setting somewhere causing this behavior. I went through every IntelliJ setting I could find and came up empty. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove related Run/Debug configurations from `Run | Edit Configurations` and re-launch your test using the green arrow in the editor window

Comment: If the problem remains contact JetBrains support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new for further assistance

Comment: Check Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Runner, then select Run test using: IntelliJ IDEA